# How to add a <tr> right underneath the selected <tr>?

Tags: jquery

I have a table and would like to add an ajax loaded  underneath the row I click with the mouse.  However I don't know how to get the index and it gets appended to the end instead.

e.g. click on "hol" and the row shall be inserted underneath "hol" row.

Please see [--> fiddle <--](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/33b3M/1/)

```
<table id="tab_open_deals" class="table table-condensed table-striped cb_table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="search_result">
    <tr>
      <td>Lunch Deal- Light</td>
      <td>39.90</td>
      <td>29 Dec 2012</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hol</td>
    <td>1499.00</td>
    <td>8 Jan 2013</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tab_open_deals tbody tr').off('click').on('click', function() {
        var row = $('<tr/>');
        $(row).load('/echo/html/', {
            html: '<td class="override" colspan="4"><table class="table-striped sub_table-hover"><thead><tr><th>Sub1</th><th>Sub2</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></tbody></table></td>'
        });

        $(this).parent().append(row);
    });
});
```

Comment: Perhaps `$().after` or `$().insertAfter` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of your function, the `id`, or index, is irrelevant; simply use a reference to the currently-clicked `tr`:

```
row.insertAfter($(this));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/33b3M/2/).

Incidentally, `row` is *already* a jQuery object (since you created it with: `row = $('<tr />')`), so you don't need to wrap it in a jQuery object in the next line `$(row).load(/*...*/)`, just use: `row.load(/*...*/)`.

Reference:

- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the index, just get a reference to the clicked `tr` ([`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) is good for that) and use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$('#tab_open_deals tbody tr').off('click').on('click', function() {
    var row = $('<tr/>');
    $(row).load('/echo/html/', {
        html: '<td class="override" colspan="4"><table class="table-striped sub_table-hover"><thead><tr><th>Sub1</th><th>Sub2</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></tbody></table></td>'
    });

    $(this).closest("tr").after(row);
});
```

But the way you're hooking the event, it won't be hooked on any new rows you add. You might consider [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate), which is for doing *event delegation* (you can also use the hyper-overloaded [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) function for event delegation in newer versions of jQuery).

Here's a simplified example:

```
$("#theTable tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
  var row = $("<tr><td></td></tr>");

  row.find("td").text("New row at " + new Date());

  $(this).after(row);
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ukezew/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ukezew/1/edit)

Or if you prefer `on` to `delegate`, change

```
$("#theTable tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
```

to

```
$("#theTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function() {
```

(Note that the order of arguments changed.) [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ukezew/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ukezew/2/edit)

---

Side notes:

- You might want to wait until the content is loaded, though, by not putting it in the DOM until the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) callback fires.
- It seems odd that you're sending an HTML fragment *to* the server (that's what the second argument to `load` does, if it's not a function). But given the name of the URL you're sending it to, I'm assuming it's correct. :-)

Comment: Thanks :) +1 from me.  I think the other answer is better because there is already a reference to the tr, hence `.closest('tr')` won't be actually necessary. Regarding teh weird load url, its just an echo to simulate ajax on jsfiddle. Thats the only way I know of. ;)

Comment: @Kave: Using `closest` is harmless and flexible. But yes, if you set up your event handler such that `this` is the `tr`, you don't need `closest` (as, in fact, I showed in my live examples of the `delegate` and `on` calls). Again, the current way you're hooking up your rows means the *new* rows won't be hooked up, whereas with the examples above, they will.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `after()`. It's like `append()`, but for siblings.

http://api.jquery.com/after/